# Ejecucion de comando en linux desde php

Tags: php, linux

Tengo el siguiente comando que deseo ejecutar en la *shell* de **`Linux`** desde `php` pero no me funciona, he utilizado `exec`, `php_exec system`. pero nada.

```
`iw dev $target station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d' '`
```

Recibo como parámetro `target` desde `php`  y me muestra un error como si los parámetros llegaran incorrectamente verifico y esta bien,  y al cambiar la variable `target` por la tarjeta directamente funciona, no sé si alguien me pueda ayudar. Utilizo `php7` y `deepinOS`.

esta es la funcion `php7.0`

```
function list_connect($interface){

 $names = file($interface);


     foreach($names as $name)
     {
         $target = $names[0];
         $broadcast = $names[1];
     }

    $query = "iw dev $target station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d' '";
    $maclist = shell_exec($query);

    var_dump($maclist);

    }   

    list_connect($path_logs_condor_TARGET_LIST);`
```

Comment: Seria de ayuda que mostraras las instrucciones **exactas** que has intentado desde PHP.

Comment: ese mismo comando te funciona en la consola de linux??

Comment: Si claro el comando funciona perfectamente,  incluso si paso la tarjeta desde php directamente también funciona,  es cuando paso la variable que sale es como resultado la ayuda del. Comando iw,  voy a subir el. Código que tengo para que ie sea más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Probé y me funciona:

```
<?php
    $query = "iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep Station | cut -f 2 -s -d' '";
    $maclist = shell_exec($query);
    var_dump($maclist);
```

Salida:

```
string(18) "xx:xx:db:xx:58:d0 "
```

Lo que no me queda claro es para que usas tu for each, si vas a ejecutar tu shell_exec fuera de el. O le pasas directamente la interfaz, o dentro de un foreach le pones el shell_exec

De igual manera creo que no esta llegando bien la interfaz por eso no te funciona. Para verificar el valor de $target hace un var_dump antes de ejecutar el shell_exec.

Seguramente no le estas pasando bien la interfaz.

Comment: Ya solucione el problema,  lo que sucedía era que la variable contenía un espacio en blanco y faltaba era limpiarla,  algo que no creía pero resultó serlo jajajajaja a,  de todas maneras muchas gracias.

Comment: Y podrías colocar como solucionado la respuesta que te sirvió. Gracias